# Making a multiindex df with dice throws

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index, random-seed

Im messing with pandas and numpy and there was a tutorial on my course summing two numbers from a dice. The tutorial used pandas but I tried using numpy too, and then compared the results.

```
throws = 50
diepd = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
dienp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
np.random.seed(1) 
sum_np = [np.random.choice(dienp,2,True).sum() for i in range(throws)] 
sum_pd = [diepd.sample(2, replace=True).sum().loc[0] for i in range(throws)]

compare = pd.DataFrame(data={'sum_np': sum_np, 'sum_pd': sum_pd})

compare
```

Im having real difficulties understanding/manipulating multiindex dataframes, so as an extra lesson, Id like to learn how to create one with the results, to compare where they differ (since Im using the same seed).

The index would be just the 50 (1 to throws) throws. The index labels, columns, would be: Level 0:
2 columns: numpy results and pandas results.

Level 1:
Three columns each:
The 2 individual throws and the sum.
For example, the two values of `np.random.choice(dienp,2,True)` and `diepd.sample(2, replace=True`, and the respective sums.

|  | numpy |  |  | pandas |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No. | throw1 | throw2 | sum | throw1 | throw2 | sum |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 7 |

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the way that you have your code, it seems very difficult to get the values of each die without looping through the trows on its own line and having values appended to lists embedded into the loop. My solution was to set up two different tables then concatenate them together after. You can see my code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

throws = 50
diepd = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
dienp = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
np.random.seed(1)
np_roll=[]
pd_roll=[]
for i in range(3):
    np_roll.append([])
    pd_roll.append([])
for i in range(throws):
    for j in range(2):
        np_roll[j].append(np.random.choice(dienp,1,True).sum())
        pd_roll[j].append(diepd.sample(1, replace=True).sum().loc[0])
        np_roll[j]=list(np_roll[j])
        pd_roll[j]=list(pd_roll[j])
    np_roll[2].append(np_roll[0][i]+np_roll[1][i])
    pd_roll[2].append(pd_roll[0][i]+pd_roll[1][i])
    

np_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Roll 1': np_roll[0], 'Roll 2': np_roll[1], "Sum": np_roll[2]})
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Roll 1': pd_roll[0], 'Roll 2': pd_roll[1], "Sum": pd_roll[2]})

compare = pd.concat([np_df, pd_df],axis=1,keys=["Numpy", "Pandas"])

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(compare)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not a problem looping, Im more interested in making the multindex.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [
    ["numpy", "numpy", "numpy", "pandas", "pandas", "pandas"],
    ["throw1", "throw2", "sum", "throw1", "throw2", "sum"]
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

throws = 50
diepd = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
dienp = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.random.seed(1)

# Create the throw1 and throw2 columns from dienp
throw1_np = np.random.choice(dienp, throws, replace=True)
throw2_np = np.random.choice(dienp, throws, replace=True)

# Create the throw1 and throw2 columns from diepd
throw1_pd = diepd.sample(throws, replace=True).values
throw2_pd = diepd.sample(throws, replace=True).values

# Create
# Add throw1 and throw2 to obtain sum
sum_np = throw1_np + throw2_np
sum_pd = throw1_pd + throw2_pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([throw1_np, throw2_np, sum_np, throw1_pd, throw2_pd, sum_pd]), columns=col_index)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: This is way above my skill level. Im going to spend a while studying it. There are some commands I havent used yet. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Just a thought... say the desired multiindex df had hundreds of level 0 and level 1 labels... would you still use this method, tuples and MI.from_tuples? For example, level 0 = "States" and level1 = "Cities", or level 0 = "Company", level 1 = various financial values?